# PyArrow Issues in Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, pyarrow

I am using Prophet lib to develop the analytics data but if we are using different source of the data, we are encountering as below kind of error.

> PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF:
> 'pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: Expected a string or bytes dtype, got
> float64

Code we are using:

```
def run_row_outlier_check(df: DataFrame, min_date, start_date, groupby_cols, job_id) -> DataFrame:
  
    pd_schema = StructType([
        StructField(groupby_col, StringType(), True),
        StructField("ds", DateType(), True),
        StructField("y", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("yhat", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("yhat_lower", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("yhat_upper", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("trend", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("trend_lower", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("trend_upper", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("additive_terms", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("additive_terms_lower", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("additive_terms_upper", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("weekly", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("weekly_lower", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("weekly_upper", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("yearly", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("yearly_lower", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("yearly_upper", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("multiplicative_terms", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("multiplicative_terms_lower", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("multiplicative_terms_upper", FloatType(), True)
        ])

    # dataframe of consecutive dates 
    df_rundates = (ps.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(start=min_date, end=(date.today() - timedelta(days=1)))})).to_spark()

    # combine + explode to create row for each date and grouped col (e.g. business segment)
    df_bizlist = (
        df.filter(f"{date_col} >= coalesce(date_sub(date 'today', {num_days_check}), '{start_date}')")
            .groupBy(groupby_col)
            .count()
            .orderBy(col("count").desc())
    )

    df_rundates_bus = (
        df_rundates
            .join(df_bizlist, how='full')
            .select(df_bizlist[groupby_col], df_rundates["date"].alias("ds"))
    )

    # create input dataframe for prophet forecast
    df_grouped_cnt = df.groupBy(groupby_cols).count()
    df_input = (
        df_rundates_bus.selectExpr(f"{groupby_col}", "to_date(ds) as ds")
            .join(df_grouped_cnt.selectExpr(f"{groupby_col}", f"{date_col} as ds", "count as y"), on=['ds',f'{groupby_col}'], how='left')
            .withColumn("y", coalesce("y", lit(0)))
            .repartition(sc.defaultParallelism, "ds")
    )
    
    # cache dataframe to improve performance
    #df_input.cache().repartition(sc.defaultParallelism, "ds")
    
    # forecast
    df_forecast = (
        df_input
            .groupBy(groupby_col)
                .applyInPandas(pd_apply_forecast, schema=pd_schema)
    )
    # filter forecast with outlier scores
    df_rowoutliers = (
        df_forecast
            .filter("y > 0 AND (y > yhat_upper OR y < array_max(array(yhat_lower,0)))")
            .withColumn("check_type", lit("row_count"))
            .withColumn("deduct_score", expr("round(sqrt(pow(y-yhat, 2) / pow(yhat_lower - yhat_upper,2)))").cast('int'))
            .select(
                col("check_type"),
                col("ds").alias("ref_date"),
                col(groupby_col).alias("ref_dimension"),
                col("y").cast('int').alias("actual"),
                col("deduct_score"),
                col("yhat").alias("forecast"),
                col("yhat_lower").alias("forecast_lower"),
                col("yhat_upper").alias("forecast_upper")
            )
    )  
    return add_metadata_columns(df_forecast, job_id), add_metadata_columns(df_rowoutliers, job_id)

def add_metadata_columns(df: DataFrame, job_id) -> DataFrame:
    """
    |    Add job metadata to dataframe
    """
    df = df.select(
        lit(f"{job_id}").cast("int").alias("job_id"),
        lit(f"{source_type}").alias("source_type"),
        lit(f"{server}").alias("server_name"),
        lit(f"{database}").alias("database_name"),
        lit(f"{table}").alias("table_name"),
        lit(f"{groupby_col}").alias("ref_dim_column"),
        lit(f"{date_col}").alias("ref_date_column"),
        df["*"],
        expr("current_timestamp()").alias("_job_timestamp"),
        expr("current_user()").alias("_job_user")
    ).withColumnRenamed(groupby_col, "ref_dimension")
    return df
```

Comment: Seems to be a schema mismatch issue for the data coming from different source. some column that should be string is being casted to float. Most probably during the enforcing of `pd_schema` on `df_forecast` Some data sample might help you to get more specific answer.

Comment: thanks for your help, i will share samples as soon as possible

Comment: Business_Segment_Desc
ds
y
yhat
yhat_lower
yhat_upper
trend
trend_lower
trend_upper
additive_terms
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
Aegis
2019-11-18
3
2.5963082
-0.4128596
5.6910996
1.7411072
1.7411072
1.7411072
0.85520107
Aegis
2019-11-19
7
2.798617
-0.4171031
5.9579816
1.7410811
1.7410811
1.7410811
1.0575359
Aegis
2019-11-20
1

Comment: BusinessSegmentKey: string
ds: date
y: integer
yhat: float
yhat_lower: float
yhat_upper: float
trend: float
trend_lower: float
trend_upper: float
additive_terms: float
additive_terms_lower: float
additive_terms_upper: float
weekly: float
weekly_lower: float
weekly_upper: float
yearly: float
yearly_lower: float
yearly_upper: float
multiplicative_terms: float
multiplicative_terms_lower: float
multiplicative_terms_upper: float

Comment: above this printschema print the value if i am trying to do display(df) throw the error

Comment: It's really hard to understand data and schema here in comments. Can you please add it in your question and then we can see if we are able to see anything useful out of it.